# i need get values this json format in java. i want to pass to jsp this value list in spring mvc

Tags: java

```
String theString="{
"0": "{\"birthPlace\":\"city1 \",\"gender\":\"m\",\"city\":\"city1 \",\"dob\":\"-\",\"homeNo\":\"city1 \",\"nic\":\"321654987\",\"fullName\":\"amith\",\"lang\":\"en\"}",
"1": "{\"birthPlace\":\"city2 \",\"gender\":\"m\",\"city2\":\"city2 \",\"dob\":\"-\",\"homeNo\":\"city2 \",\"nic\":\"22336655\",\"fullName\":\"sumith\",\"lang\":\"en\"}",
"2": "{\"birthPlace\":\"city3 \",\"gender\":\"m\",\"city2\":\"city3 \",\"dob\":\"-\",\"homeNo\":\"city3 \",\"nic\":\"88556699\",\"fullName\":\"samith\",\"lang\":\"en\"}"
}"
```

This is my response. i read this as a string.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object jj;

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(theString.getBytes());

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

jj = parser.parse(new BufferedReader(br1));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jj;

if(jsonobject!=null){

    String city= (String) jsonObject.get("city");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use java objects and GSON to convert it to JSON to pass it within different pages.

```
public class Car {
    public String brand = null;
    public int    doors = 0;
}
```

Here is an example of generating JSON from a Java object with GSON:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.brand = "Rover";
car.doors = 5;

Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(car);
```

Its simple and easy to use.
https://github.com/google/gson

And [these](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html) are some things you can do with GSON